# Optimized way to partition a class of objects based on an attribute in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, optimization, big-o, partitioning

I have a class that has million of items and each item has a **label** of type **int**. I need to partition items based on their similar labels, so at the end I return a `vector<MyClass>`. First, I sort all items based on their label. Then, in a for loop I compare each label value with previous one and if its the same I store it in a `myclass_temp` until `label != previous_label`. If `label != previous_label` I add this `myclass_temp` to the `vector<MyClass>`, and I erase `myclass_temp`. I think the code is self-explained. 
The program works fine, but it is slow, is there a better way to speed it up? I believe because I sort the items in the beginning, there should be a faster way to simply partition items with similar labels.

Second question is how to calculate O score for this algorithm and any suggested faster solution?
please feel free to correct my code.

```
 vector <MyClass> PartitionByLabels(MyClass &myclass){

    /// sort MyClass items based on label number
    printf ("Sorting items by label number... \n");
    std::sort(myclass.begin(), myclass.end(), compare_labels);

    vector <MyClass> myClasses_vec;
    MyClass myclass_temp;

    int previous_label=0, label=0;
    int total_items;

    /// partition myclass items based on similar labels
    for (int i=0; i < myclass.size(); i++){

        label = myclass[i].label;
        if (label == previous_label){
            myclass_temp.push_back(myclass[i]);
            previous_label = label;

            /// add the last similar items
            if (i == myclass.size()-1){
                myClasses_vec.push_back(myclass_temp);
                total_items +=myclass_temp.size();
            }
        } else{
            myClasses_vec.push_back(myclass_temp);
            total_items +=myclass_temp.size();

            myclass_temp.EraseItems();
            myclass_temp.push_back(myclass[i]);
            previous_label = label;
        }
    }

    printf("Total number of items: %d \n", total_items);
    return myClasses_vec;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [`std::partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This algorithm should do it. I removed the templates to make it easier to check on godbolt.

Should be easy enough to put back in.

The O score for this method is that of std::sort - O(N.log(N))

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

struct thing
{
    std::string label;
    std::string value;
};

using MyClass = std::vector<thing>;
using Partitions = std::vector<MyClass>;

auto compare_labels = [](thing const& l, thing const& r) {
    return l.label < r.label;
};

// pass by value - we need a copy anyway and we might get copy elision
Partitions PartitionByLabels(MyClass myclass){

    /// sort MyClass items based on label number
    std::sort(myclass.begin(), myclass.end(), compare_labels);

    Partitions result;

    auto first = myclass.begin();
    auto last = myclass.end();

    // because the range is sorted, we can partition it in linear time.
    // choosing the correct algorithm is always the best optimisation
    while (first != last) 
    {
        auto next = std::find_if(first, last, [&first](auto const& x) { return x.label != first->label; });

        // let's move the items - that should speed things up a little
        // this is safe because we took a copy
        result.push_back(MyClass(std::make_move_iterator(first), 
                                 std::make_move_iterator(next)));
        first = next;
    }

    return result;
}
```

We can of course do better with unordered maps, **if**:

- the label is hashable and equality-comparable
- we don't need to order the output (if we did, we'd use a multimap instead)

The O-score for this method is linear time O(N)

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <unordered_map>

struct thing
{
    std::string label;
    std::string value;
};

using MyClass = std::vector<thing>;
using Partitions = std::vector<MyClass>;

// pass by value - we need a copy anyway and we might get copy elision
Partitions PartitionByLabels(MyClass const& myclass){

    using object_type = MyClass::value_type;
    using label_type = decltype(std::declval<object_type>().label);
    using value_type = decltype(std::declval<object_type>().value);

    std::unordered_multimap<label_type, value_type> inter;
    for(auto&& x : myclass) {
        inter.emplace(x.label, x.value);
    }

    Partitions result;

    auto first = inter.begin();
    auto last = inter.end();

    while (first != last) 
    {
        auto range = inter.equal_range(first->first);
        MyClass tmp;
        tmp.reserve(std::distance(range.first, range.second));
        for (auto i = range.first ; i != range.second ; ++i) {
            tmp.push_back(object_type{i->first, std::move(i->second)});
        }
        result.push_back(std::move(tmp));
        first = range.second;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What does `std::make_move_iterator` do? Why do we need it?

Comment: @Bruce it creates an iterator that calls `std::move` on the object it de-references. It means that provided you have obeyed the rules of zero, 3 or 5, then moving objects between the containers becomes extremely quick.
However, you can ignore that part as its just an optimisation. The real point is that we have reduced the collation algorithm into a single pass.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Then you mean with the second algorithm, i don't need to sort the data beforehand? And another question is, do I need to replace `auto` with type of `myclass::iterator`? Why do you use `auto`, does it make any difference?

Comment: @Bruce both algorithms are in two parts. The first is like yours, except that for the second part we are able to convert it into linear time, which is dwarfed by the cost of the sort. The second uses the fact that unordered_map lookups are constant-time and insertions are on average O(1), which is a massive win.

Comment: And how about `auto` should I change them to MyClass::iterator? I mean does it make any difference in the code using `auto` instead of the real type?

Comment: @Bruce `auto` allows the compiler to deduce the type. This makes it much easier to code and you don't have to work it out for yourself. It's particularly helpful with template programming.

Comment: I tried the first algorithm, it works fine and fast, the only problem is I loose my class attributes. So in the output there is no label or other attributes of myclass objectype. For the **second algorithm**, it seems that my compiler <I use mingw and gcc 4.7> doesn't support `std::unordered_multimap`, so I used `std::multimap` instead. But I am getting a lot of compiling errors, for example this line `tmp.push_back(object_type{i->first, std::move(i->second)})` I am not sure to replace `object_type` with what in my template? I appreciate your input.

Comment: It sound like you're using an old compiler. I have assumed, since it's 2017 that you at least had c++14. The version of c++ was not marked in the question. Re the first version, I don't know all the nuances of your actual objects so you'll have to fill in the blanks yourself. The point of the answer is that you can reduce the second part of the process to linear time since the objects are all sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a map from ints to vectors, iterate through the original vector once, adding each `MyClass` object to `TheMap[myclass[i].label]`? It takes your average runtime from `f(n + n*log(n))` to `f(n)`.

Comment: So you mean I make a map like map<MyClass, int> and loop through all items and insert myclass object and label to map. Then each map represents one single item, right? It doesn't give me a collection of similar labels.

Comment: map<int, vector<MyClass>> - As you iterate through the objects, you just push each one to the back of the vector at map_of_my_class[instance.label]. If returning the map doesn't work for you, and you still want to return a vector of vectors, you could iterate through the keys in the map to generate that structure, but that's still far faster than what you're doing now, though it risks an f(n+n) runtime.